How to display a RealityKit Perspective Camera View in a visionOS SwiftUI 2D window?
I am developing an immersive visionOS app based on RealityKit and SwiftUI.
This app has ModelEntities that have a PerspectiveCamera entity as child.
I want to display the camera view in a 2D window in visionOS.
I am creating the camera, and add it to the entity with
let cameraEntity = PerspectiveCamera()
cameraEntity.camera.far = 10000
cameraEntity.camera.fieldOfViewInDegrees = 60
cameraEntity.camera.near = 0.01

entity.addChild(cameraEntity)

There are some post on SO, like this one, that apparently show such camera views as part of an arView. However my app is not AR. The immersive view is programmatically generated.
My question is:
How can I show the camera view in a SwiftUI 2D window?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/perspectivecamera

@loremipsum Thanks for the link, but I did read the docu. PerspectiveCamera has a camera property of type PerspectiveCameraComponent that allows to set various camera properties. My question was: How can I show the image of the PerspectiveCamera in a SwiftUI View window? I could not find any hint.

using the non AR camera mode + the sample you posted. SwiftUI isn't capable on its own you need an ARView

But ARView is not available in visionOS, that's the problem...

I contacted Apple, and they confirmed that this is a bug in visionOS 1.0 … 2.0 beta: One can currently define a PerspectiveCamera, but cannot use its output.
They suggested to use a RealityRenderer instead. Here is the suggested code that I did not check until now.
@Observable
@MainActor
final class OffscreenRenderModel {
        
    private let renderer: RealityRenderer
    
    private let colorTexture: MTLTexture
        
    init(scene: Entity) throws {
        renderer = try RealityRenderer()
        
        renderer.entities.append(scene)
        
        let camera = PerspectiveCamera()
        renderer.activeCamera = camera
        renderer.entities.append(camera)
        
        let textureDesc = MTLTextureDescriptor()
        textureDesc.pixelFormat = .rgba8Unorm
        textureDesc.width = 512
        textureDesc.height = 512
        textureDesc.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead]
        
        let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
        colorTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDesc)!
    }
    
    func render() throws {
        
        let cameraOutputDesc = RealityRenderer.CameraOutput.Descriptor.singleProjection(colorTexture: colorTexture)
        
        let cameraOutput = try RealityRenderer.CameraOutput(cameraOutputDesc)

        try renderer.updateAndRender(deltaTime: 0.1, cameraOutput: cameraOutput, onComplete: { renderer in
            
            guard let colorTexture = cameraOutput.colorTextures.first else { fatalError() }
            
            // The colorTexture holds the rendered scene.
        })
    }
}

